# Excluding NaT/Null values while performing Date Comparison in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe like the following,

```
  Travel Date
0  2020-09-23
1  2020-09-24
2  2020-09-30
3         NaT
4  2015-10-15
5  2018-07-30
6         NaT
7  2019-09-25
8  2018-06-05
```

And I wanted to check whether some custom given date is greater than the data present in the 'Travel  Date' column and write the result in a new column as Passed but I wanted to ignore the column containing NaT.

But at the moment, it is taking the column with NaT also for the comparison and writing the result as Passed.

```
  Travel Date  Detail
0  2020-09-23  Passed
1  2020-09-24  Passed
2  2020-09-30     NaN
3         NaT  Passed
4  2015-10-15  Passed
5  2018-07-30  Passed
6         NaT  Passed
7  2019-09-25  Passed
8  2018-06-05  Passed
```

Tried the following code, but it is including the column NaT also for the comparison and writing as Passed.

```
df1['Travel Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Travel Date'])
test = df1['Travel Date'] > '2020-09-29  12:00:00'
df1.loc[~test, "Detail"] = "Passed"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison with `NaN` always results in `False`. So you can just revert your condition:

```
df['Detail'] = np.where(df['Travel Date'] <= '2020-09-29  12:00:00', 'Passed', np.nan)
```

Or similarly:

```
df.loc[df['Travel Date'] <= '2020-09-29  12:00:00', 'Detail'] = 'Passed'
```

Output:

```
  Travel Date  Detail
0  2020-09-23  Passed
1  2020-09-24  Passed
2  2020-09-30     nan
3         NaT     nan
4  2015-10-15  Passed
5  2018-07-30  Passed
6         NaT     nan
7  2019-09-25  Passed
8  2018-06-05  Passed
```

Comment: Can you also help me in telling, how we can perform a similar comparison with more dates in different columns. [Here is my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64994520/comparing-date-with-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check for NaT:

```
df1['Travel Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Travel Date'])
test = (df1['Travel Date'] > '2020-09-29  12:00:00') & (~pd.isna(df1['Travel Date']))
df1.loc[~test, "Detail"] = "Passed"
```